# Matlab horizontal asymptote being calculated incorrectly

Tags: matlab, limit

From an lsqcurve fit function I am trying to calculate the horizontal asymptote of a sigmoidal curve over the data range.  The code I am using to do this and convert the output to double precision works and is as follows:

```
time = [0,0.166666666666667,0.333333333333333,0.500000000000000,0.666666666666667,0.833333333333333,1,1.16666666666667,1.33333333333333,1.50000000000000,1.66666666666667,1.83333333333333,2,2.16663888888889,2.33330555555556,2.49997222222222,2.66663888888889,2.83330555555556,2.99997222222222,3.16663888888889,3.33330555555556,3.49997222222222,3.66663888888889,3.83330555555556,3.99997222222222,4.16663888888889,4.33330555555556,4.49997222222222,4.66663888888889,4.83330555555556,4.99997222222222,5.16663888888889,5.33327777777778,5.49997222222222,5.66661111111111,5.83327777777778,5.99994444444444,6.16661111111111,6.33327777777778,6.49994444444444,6.66661111111111,6.83327777777778,6.99994444444444,7.16661111111111,7.33327777777778,7.49994444444444,7.66661111111111,7.83327777777778,7.99994444444444,8.16661111111111,8.33327777777778,8.49994444444445,8.66661111111111,8.83325000000000,8.99991666666667,9.16658333333333,9.33325000000000,9.49991666666667,9.66658333333333,9.83325000000000,9.99991666666667,10.1665833333333,10.3332500000000,10.4999166666667,10.6665833333333,10.8332500000000,10.9999166666667,11.1665833333333,11.3332500000000,11.4999166666667,11.6665833333333,11.8332222222222,11.9998888888889,12.1665555555556,12.3332222222222,12.4998888888889,12.6665555555556,12.8332222222222,12.9998888888889,13.1665555555556,13.3332222222222,13.4998888888889,13.6665555555556,13.8332222222222,13.9998888888889,14.1665555555556,14.3332222222222,14.4998888888889,14.6665555555556,14.8332222222222,14.9998611111111,15.1665277777778,15.3331944444444,15.4998611111111];
Abs=[0.0756333346168200,,0.0822666635115941,0.101066668828328,0.125066662828128,0.147433335582415,0.169966672857602,0.192199997603893,0.211166655023893,0.231433339416981,0.256133330365022,0.279866663118203,0.295566670596600,0.309466672440370,0.323400000731150,0.335233343144258,0.348299992581209,0.359700001776218,0.371433332562447,0.383333327869574,0.394433322052161,0.404166663686434,0.413666687905788,0.423499998946985,0.432733344535033,0.443266667425633,0.453899989525477,0.463699989020824,0.475066669285297,0.485300009449323,0.495999989410241,0.504966656366984,0.514033327500025,0.523766654233138,0.532566664119562,0.541033337513606,0.550333333512147,0.559733323752880,0.567733330031236,0.575466672579447,0.583399988710880,0.591433353722096,0.597833327949047,0.604699979225794,0.610233349104722,0.616733354826768,0.622800009946028,0.628666676580906,0.634199996789297,0.638966679573059,0.644799992442131,0.650733329355717,0.654566655556361,0.661333315074444,0.666366661588351,0.671233326196671,0.675699991484483,0.679433315992355,0.682733337084452,0.686333330969016,0.689166650176048,0.693133344252904,0.697366672257582,0.699333322544893,0.702233329415321,0.705400002499422,0.707699996729692,0.709999985992909,0.711533337831497,0.712800003588200,0.713633326192697,0.714666672050953,0.714533333977064,0.713999989132086,0.714266665279865,0.714066684246063,0.714266670246919,0.713733327885469,0.713066659867764,0.712200003365676,0.711600005626679,0.710400002698104,0.710399977862835,0.709799999992053,0.708366667230924,0.706933336953322,0.706766667465369,0.706199998656909,0.704266687234243,0.703333348035812,0.702399998903275,0.701133318245411,0.700166669984659,0.698799995084604,0.697700018684069];
u=linspace(0,15.49986111,500);
v=pchip(time,Abs,u);
p0 = [0.075633335,0.05,0.01];  %First value = Abs value at t=0
options=optimset('MaxFunEvals',10000,'MaxIter',5000,'Display','iter');
[p,error,residual]=lsqcurvefit(@gompertz,p0,time,Abs,[],[],options)    
syms x t
f=p(1)*exp(-exp(((p(2)*exp(1))/p(1))*(p(3)-t)+1));

f1=diff(f,t);                        %Find first derivative of equation W wrt t
f2=diff(f,t,2);                      %Find second derivative wrt t and to allow inflection point to be defined
crit_pts = solve(f1);                %Find local maxima and minima   
crit_pts=double(crit_pts);
flimit = limit(f,inf);               %Find find horizontal asymptote of function f by taking limit of f as x approaches infinity
function_horizontal_asymptote=double(limit);
```

The 'gompertz' function called is coded as follows:

```
function y = gompertz(p,t)

y=p(1)*exp(-exp(((p(2)*exp(1))/p(1))*(p(3)-t)+1));
```

According to the Matlab documentation I have read

```
flimit = limit(f,inf);
```

should yield the correct answer but and appear towards the end of the time course, however the result I get is (shown by the yellow marker):

[image]

Am I calculating this incorrectly?

Thank you for your time,

Laura

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible, please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you check your fit to your data? That limit is only as good as the fit is in `t=inf`. And can't you compute the limit of that function on paper, and substitute the fitted parameters into the result?

Comment: If none of the parameters are zero, the limit should be `p(1)` if `p(2)/p(1)` is positive, and `0` if `p(2)/p(1)` is negative. Unless I'm mistaken, of course.

Comment: Thank you Andras Deak, that works! However I now cannot plot this value (0.72467) as a y-value, only as an x.  Could you please tell me how to obtain the x-axis value at this point so I can plot this value correctly?

Comment: Sure: the x axis value is `x=inf` :) I suggest something like a [`refline`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/refline.html) or just a manual plot between `0` and `xmax`, to indicate the horizontal asymptote.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help:) However, I believe your question is unlikely to help future readers, and you should consider deleting it (there won't be any repercussions for you if you do so, as long as there are no answers on a question of yours that you're planning to delete). If you disagree, please add an answer of your own to have a question-and-answer pair:)

Comment: I will, thanks again :)